# OpenCV linker error with libraries after update

Tags: c++, shell, opencv, makefile

I was using OpenCV but for some reason needed to install it again!
But my program doesn't compile now!
My compile script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -gt 0 ] ; then
#   base=`basename $1 .c`
#   echo "compiling $base"
#   gcc -ggdb `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` $base.c -o $base 

#   base=`basename $1 .cpp`
    echo "compiling $1"
    g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o `basename $1 .cpp` $1 `pkg-config --libs opencv`;
#   gcc -ggdb `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` $base.c -o $base 

else
    for i in *.c; do
        echo "compiling $i"
        gcc -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o `basename $i .c` $i `pkg-config --libs opencv`;
    done
    for i in *.cpp; do
        echo "compiling $i"
        g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o `basename $i .cpp` $i `pkg-config --libs opencv`;
    done
fi
```

and when I use it like `./build_all.sh test10Camera.cpp` it doesn't work the output and error is:

```
compiling test10Camera.cpp
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libtbb.so, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `tbb::task_scheduler_init::initialize(int)'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `tbb::task::note_affinity(unsigned short)'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so: undefined reference to `tbb::internal::handle_perror(int, char const*)'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_child_proxy::allocate(unsigned int) const'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::is_group_execution_cancelled() const'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `tbb::task_scheduler_init::terminate()'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `tbb::task_scheduler_init::initialize(int, unsigned int)'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `typeinfo for tbb::task'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_continuation_proxy::allocate(unsigned int) const'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `vtable for tbb::task'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_root_with_context_proxy::free(tbb::task&) const'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::init()'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `tbb::task_scheduler_init::default_num_threads()'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `tbb::internal::get_initial_auto_partitioner_divisor()'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::~task_group_context()'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_root_with_context_proxy::allocate(unsigned int) const'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is wrong and what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is telling you exactly what's wrong:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libtbb.so, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

Go get `libtbb` and install it, or if you already have, make sure your compiler knows where to find it.